How can I fix this Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen' Require stack: Error when I start my react app?
Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:

C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
C:\Users\kyawz\Documents\React Project\testing\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

This error happens on the terminal in every react app that I create. How can I prevent this error even thought I create a new react app?

you can check  package-lock.json and try re-install your node module again

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install


I hope this can help you
or you can try this one Thanks! for this
npm ls ajv
npm install --save-dev ajv@^8

